# Codeigniter 3.0 not displaying all sessions in ubuntu even if all settings are correct

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu-16.04

Codeigniter 3.0 displayes only

```
Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1522220387 )
```

and remaining sessions not displayed, any solution for this

Comment: by "remaining sessions" do you mean, "other session variables that I set previously to doing `print_r($_SESSION)`;"?

Comment: yes other session variables that I set previously

Comment: can you show me how you set variables into session @Shadab

Comment: $session_array = array(
                        "userid" => $data->user_id,
                        "username" => $data->name);
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $session_array);
when  i am using print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
it is displaying only Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1522236584 )..any solution for this will be appreciated

Comment: I have at least 5 different Ubuntu servers with websites that are using CodeIgniter 3 sessions. I think you misunderstand the configuration or usage of sessions.